# Fuzzy Startswith

Tags: python, startswith

Is there a way to perform a fuzzy "startswith" such that if the first string starts with something close to the second, it will return true? My first thought is to use an edit distance threshold, but I'm not sure how to do that in the context of startswith.

Example:

```
first_str = "My nam is Hello World"
second_str = "My name is"        
first_str.startswith(second_str) == True
```

Comment: It depends on what counts as `close`. You might want to look into [Levenshtein Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)

Comment: can you provide more examples of fuzzy startswith that return `True`, how many many differences are allowed, does it matter the order?

Comment: I would say my threshold would be a Levenshtein distance ratio above 0.8 or so. I can add more examples if that's helpful though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

fuzzywuzzy can help sort of

```
>>> from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
>>> fuzz.partial_ratio("my name is joran","my nam is")
```

you will need to `pip install fuzzywuzzy` then you just need to pick a ratio that is "True" this does not necesarily mean "it startswith" we could do that with a helper function though

```
def fuzzy_startswith(needle,haystack):
    n_words = len(needle.split())
    haystack_startswith = " ".join(haystack.split()[:n_words])
    return fuzz.ratio(needle,haystack_startswith)

fuzzy_startswith("my nam is","my name is joran")
```

Comment: Also, you might want to convert everything to the same case, e.g. `.upper()` or `.lower()`.  `fuzzywuzzy` seems to be case dependent (by default anyway).  This can yield less than intuitive results:  `haystack='MY NAME is joran'` returns 40.  `haystack='my uncle is joran'` returns 74.